# Error Showing whenever I try to post without img Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to create a social media but whenever I try to post some post without an image field it's throwing me an Error saying "**The 'post_img' attribute has no file associated with it.**". It works fine when I post something with the image but I want it to be like Twitter where you can post a blog and Image. So I don't know what's going on.

[image]

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from PIL import Image

# Create your models here.
class PostTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(null = True, blank=True)
    post_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "posts_img", null = True, blank = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    post_tag = models.ForeignKey(PostTag, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null= True,blank=True) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} / {self.author}"
    if post_img:
        def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

            img = Image.open(self.post_img.path)

            if img.height > 600 or img.width > 600:
                output_size = (600, 600)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.post_img.path)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PostCreateForm
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url="users:index")
def posts_view(request):
    form = PostCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Posted your Post")
        return redirect("posts:posts_view")
    else:
        form = PostCreateForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "posts.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is this particular snippet of code:

```
if post_img:
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

This obviously **does not** do what you suppose it does. The if-statement is only processed while the class is being declared / created. Hence that if-statement only finds the `ImageField` you have declared, finds that it is **truthy** and then overrides `save` permanently. Instead you want to move such logic *inside* the method you are writing:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(null = True, blank=True)
    post_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "posts_img", null = True, blank = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    post_tag = models.ForeignKey(PostTag, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null= True,blank=True) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} / {self.author}"
    
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.post_img: # Move if inside the method!
            img = Image.open(self.post_img.path)
            if img.height > 600 or img.width > 600:
                output_size = (600, 600)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.post_img.path)
```

Comment: I have tried with this logic but the result is still the same shows the same error

Comment: @AakashThapa please add the _full_ error traceback to your question (not that image)